# Spring Boot app in Intellij: Debug takes 10x longer than Run

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Idea 2020.3.3. I have a number of Spring Boot apps (microservices) that I've been running for almost 2 years. One day I started them up in the debugger, and it now takes ~200 seconds to initialize, versus ~25 seconds without the debugger. Nothing changed from one day to the next - Debug mode just started 10x longer.

I'm not sure what information would be helpful to show here to diagnose this. Does anyone have a generic checklist of things that generally cause debug to slow down so drastically? It's not just the initialization - the whole application has become so slow that it's impossible to use. This applies to all of my apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breakpoints on Class Fields lead to this behavior here.

Also this article maybe helpful: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping

Comment: I've seen this while executing the app, but not while just initializing? Still, I'll make sure I have no class breakpoints and let you know, thanks.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. I had a field watch breakpoint and you were absolutely right!! Now it starts up like a charm. THANK YOU.

Comment: I'm trying to accept your answer but it's not letting me...

Comment: @CNDyson When I've a single breakpoint on a class field then the whole application from startup to every single action takes at least 10x of normal execution time. Even opening a new page takes seconds instead of 200 millis or so.